# How to Change Values of Serialized Data in RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

First, I would like to present how my managers, models, serializers and views look like upfront.

```py
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    """
    Only published articles. `due_date` is past.
    """

    def get_queryset(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return super().get_queryset().filter(due_date__lt=now)


class UnpublishedManager(models.Manager):
    """
    Only unpublished articles. `due_date` is future.
    """

    def announced(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(announced=True)

    def get_queryset(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return super().get_queryset().filter(due_date__gt=now)


class Article(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    due_date = models.DateTimeField()
    announced = models.BooleanField()

    # managers
    objects = models.Manager()  # standard manager
    published = PublishedManager()
    unpublished = UnpublishedManager()


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ("content", "due_date")


class ArticleRUDView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
```

In this code, `ArticleRUDView` naturally responds with all `Article` because of `Article.objects.all()`, yet this is not what I want to do. What I want to do is:

- If the user is authenticated, then `Article.objects.all()`.
- If the user is anonymous,

  - If the entry is published (which means its `due_date` is less than `now`), then serialize all fields.
  - If the entry is not published (which means its `due_date` is greater than `now`), then **still serialize**, but `content` should be `null` in JSON.

Or, in short, how do I alter the serializer's data in a view?

## Troubleshooting

This section might get updated in time. I will elaborate on what I find.

### Overriding `get_serializer` Method from `GenericAPIView`

So I've found out I can get an instance of `ArticleSerializer`. So I did below:

```py
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = super().get_serializer()
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        return serializer

    obj = self.get_object()  # get_object, hence the name, gets the object
    due_date = obj.due_date
    now = timezone.now()

    if due_date > now:
        serializer.data["content"] = None

    return serializer
```

However, my tests didn't go well at all. This, oddly, returns an **empty string** on `content` field in JSON. I've tried different things but got that empty string. I do not have any single clue about what to do from here.

---

## Environment

- Python 3.7.4
- Django 2.2.7
- Django Rest Framework 3.10.3

Comment: why don't you use a different serializer for when the user is authenticated or not? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself

Comment: Well, that's a way to do. I don't know actually. Writing the same fields twice under different serializers turned me off I think. | Okay, Now ı see `get_serializer_class` and that starts to make sense. Let me consider.

Comment: I know how you feel but it could prevent you from defining complex business rules in your `get_serializer_class`

Comment: Seems you are right about that. I would also primarily prefer writing new structures (I mean, classes) rather than using `if` myself. Thank you so much. It gives me insights.

Comment: I think you have to override `get_serializer` method as well as `get_queryset`. Both methods should contain almost the same logic

Comment: @JPG I already override `get_serializer` as seen above, which results in an odd response where, whatever the case, `content` is an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `get_serializer_class` as opposed to `get_serializer`.  You can allow the serializer class to choose what to stick in `content` instead of all the mucking around with managers, since you want to serialize all objects anyway.  Something like this should work:

```py
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ("content", "due_date")

class AnonymousArticleSerializer(ArticleSerializer):
    content = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_content(obj):
        if obj.due_date > timezone.now():
            return None
        return obj.content

class ArticleRUDView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Article.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.serializer_class:
            return self.serializer_class

        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            self.serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
        else:
            self.serializer_class = AnonymousArticleSerializer

        return self.serializer_class
```

One thing I don't like about this solution is that if you have a more complicated serializer field you're overwriting, you'd have to put the logic somewhere, but in this case (`context` being a text field) it's pretty simple.

Comment: I think this is the best way with no hacks. Accepted.

Comment: Great.  Glad I could help!